# Double encryption

Tags: java, security, encryption

I am using https://github.com/simbiose/Encryption to encrypt data in my android app.

I thought of double encryption.

```
String key = "key";
String salt = "someSalt";
byte[] iv = new byte[16];
Encryption encryption = Encryption.getDefault(key, salt, iv);

String encrypted = encryption.encryptOrNull("Some String");

Log.d("Encrypto", "Encryption Level 1 : "+encrypted);

encrypted = encryption.encryptOrNull(encrypted);

Log.d("Encrypto", "Encryption Level 2 : "+encrypted);

String decrypted = encryption.decryptOrNull(encrypted);

Log.d("Encrypto", "Decryption Level 2 : "+decrypted);

decrypted = encryption.decryptOrNull(decrypted);

Log.d("Encrypto", "Decryption Level 1 : "+decrypted);
```

**This works perfectly**, but is it recommended?

1. yes this increases the memory usage to store the encrypted string, but if it makes it more secure, using more memory is pretty okay.
2. Will i face some problems if i do this ?

Main question: is this a good encryption library? if not please recommend me a better one

Comment: Using a fixed IV is insecure.  Encrypt as many times as you like, it won't help you if you're using a fixed IV...

Comment: you're also encrypting with the same key. If someone gets the key you could encrypt 1000 times and it won't matter.

Comment: Since the encryption algorithm us unknown **do not use** simbiose, snake oil at best. Use a standard such as AES (Advanced Encryption Standard). With a secure encryption method the security is in a good key that can not be easily found, AES with a 128-bit random key is secure.

Answer (score 5):

Do you really need to encrypt the data?

https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2015/06/why_we_encrypt.html

Why do you want double encryption? There are better ways - for example, a longer key - to add resistance against people performing offline brute force attacks on cipher text.

"*Security through obscurity*" is a no-no.  Go back to the basics of what you need (key length, block size, mode of encryption, when to use a symmetric or asymmetric key) etc.

As you are writing an Android app, I would question..

- The library is written in Java and makes Java
  system calls. That will be simple to reverse / hook system calls.  Does adding a longer key help harden your app when you can dump the key by hooking an Android system call?
- your Android Java code is de-compiled to "almost" source code or back
  to Smali code - then modified - and then re-compiled?
- How are you intending to distribute the key ?  Run-time or statically baked into the code?  Is it random or the same key for all app users?
- Can you leverage Android hardware to persist and protect your key, instead of just having the key in software?  https://source.android.com/security/keystore/

If it was my app && I cared about **Confidentiality**  I would use hardware backed encryption (accepting that some older Android devices might not support it) OR use a Native (C) encryption library.  The latter gets you wide device support but introduces other issues (JNI boundary, code lifting).

In summary, introducing encryption sounds simple.  But do you really need it when it just highlights something interesting is being protected?

PS - You may want to re-post this question on: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

> This works perfectly, but is it recommended?

Short answer: No

Answer: With a stream cipher, double encryption with the same parameters (key, IV, nonce, counter, etc.) as you show us will produce the clear text, allowing everyone to read your data.