# Work safely with AES keys (Android server)

Tags: android, encryption, aes, rsa

From Android -> I encrypt files that I send to the server, later I receive those same files again and I have to be able to decrypt them.

From Server -> I save those encrypted files to return them when necessary and also to decrypt them.

The AES key to encrypt / decrypt must be known by Android and server. Currently my AES and IV key are insecure and are written in the code.

Keep in mind that if I upload an encrypted file to the server and I want to download it 2 months later, I have to know the password with which it was encrypted. The server does not encrypt, only returns encrypted files that it received or decrypts them for other operations.

I have thought about generating the AES key in Android, and that Android send it securely through an RSA to the server. This is safe ? So each user would have their own AES password for all their files, and would only send it once with RSA to the server.

How can I do this to have more security?

Comment: Just use HTTPS and let all the encryption take place on the server. You're overcomplicating things.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark  If he/she doesn't care about the Integrity of the data, your idea does get rid of the complexity & avoids generating keys on the client and all of the other complexity you inherit.  But is the data really Confidential?  Does he care if somebody tampers with the data?  If yes to either, TLS alone is not enough.

have a look at https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2017/12/security_vulner_10.html.  Then look at OWASP https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Pinning_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @rustyMagnet Can you explain why TLS alone is not enough?  I assumed an AEAD mode like GCM for the server-side encryption if this is what you are referring to about integrity.  TLS also preserves data integrity.  I'm not sure why you think TLS is not enough.

Comment: Set up a valid man-in-the-middle and you can read and tamper with all the data in transit from a mobile device, if you don't use cert pinning.  https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1841101-configuring-an-android-device-to-work-with-burp

Comment: @rustyMagnet "if you don't use cert pinning" - then use cert pinning?  Additionally, what you've linked requires physical access to the device -  if you had this access then you wouldn't need to MITM, you'd already have access to the files.  The threat model is important here.

Comment: Yes, use cert pinning.  Your comment misses the point; if I install his app, I have the ability - whether it is rooted or not - to find his encryption key within minutes.  If you are sending keys, inside TLS connections, I will find the key within seconds.

Comment: @rustyMagnet No, you won't, because the encryption and decryption takes place on the server...  That was the whole point to begin with remember?  In my very first comment?  And even if it wasn't - why would you encrypt with a *fixed* key client-side?  That makes no sense.

Comment: If your only requirement is to secure the client-server communications then you can't do better than TLS. TLS has had decades of analysis and tuning.

Answer (score 0):

- If you can do encryption and decryption on the server side, so do that.
- Always use SSL for data transfer between entities.
- Try to use a unique key for each session.
- IV can be sent plain.
- Use secure random for generating IVs and keys.
- Do not use ECB mode.
- Use standard padding mode.
- Try AES with key size 256 or higher.
- When you send the encrypted file to the server, try to send key and
  store them on the server side. You can get both key and encrypted text later.
- You can generate the key on the phone with key derivation algorithm
  like PBKDF2 from user input. This method does not need to save the password but this requires to execute
  PBKDF2 each time from user input.
- Never try to implement security through obscurity.

Security is step by step methods and each step depends on the importance of your data.

Comment: Did you mean "key length = 256 bits"?  AES is always Block size 128 bits.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

Comment: @rustyMagnet Yes, the key size is important. When we say AES 256 or RSA 2048, we always mention the key size, not the block size.

Comment: If you are using TLS and encryption/decrypton takes place on the server, everything else is unnecessary.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Yes, but what I have mentioned is generally. Regardless of being on the server side or the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to encrypt the data ?

(https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2015/06/why_we_encrypt.html)

Like your question suggests, if you do have a ***Confidentiality*** requirement, you inherit other challenges.  Some of the most well known are **Key Distribution, Key Rotation** and **Key Agreement**.

If you decide, you need to encrypt the data and both sides do require the key, I would look at ...

- Key Agreement protocol; [Diffie–Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).  This gives a notable benefit for a mobile app; you don't have to send the Key to each other.  In the Android/iOS context that is especially useful when people can employ relatively simple methods to defeat TLS or Certificate Pinning protections.
- Removing hardcoded keys from code.  First, you have a single key for every single app that is out in use.  How would you ever rotate this key?  If you proceed with this route, you could consider further hardening.  You can find libraries that encrypt strings at-rest, that harden it against static code analysis.  Still, this protection does not help against a debugger searching for a particular pattern in your apk.
- Hardware backed security.  If you only care about newer Android devices, I would alway try and use hardware-back crypto for key generation or key storage.  https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.  It has Key Generation (https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator).

There is another, slightly related Android encryption question here: [Double encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51452844/double-encryption/51453523?noredirect=1#comment89880662_51453523)

PS - you might want to post this on:  https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Based on the OP's statement in the last paragraph, about sending the AES key to the server, everything in your answer is unnecessary: HTTPS/TLS solves this issue directly without every having to touch any cryptography code.